# Quantum mechanics prediction for Bremsstrahlung?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, radiation

Does quantum mechanics predict the Bremsstrahlung Phenomena? I know it is predicted by classical mechanics through Maxwell's equations, but does QM predict this phenomena and how so?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung#Quantum_mechanical_description

Comment: sorry but this doesn't answer my question as Beth-Heitler approach computed the Cross-section for Bremsstrahlung and their approach did not include the interaction of Z electrons for incident particle traversing the medium plus the screening effect and the solution is not clear for me, i just want to understand how QM is utilized to predict this phenomena. i appreciate your efforts :)

Comment: @AOnsi I hate it when people just leave a link of wiki and let it go as if everything is simple as that and as if we did not think looking it up on wiki....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes , here are Feynman diagrams for [bremsstrahlung](http://brock.physik.uni-bonn.de/~brock/feynman/ktp_ws1011/):

[image: bremsstrahlung]

From these the cross section can be computed.

Comment: Could you please, explain how QFT predicted Bremsstrahlung through Feynman Diagram.

Comment: In QED diagrams that can be written consistent with the rules and  conservation laws can be transcribed into intergrals with specific format and content. The integration yields the crossection. The reason quantum mechanics is accepted as the underlying level of classical theories is becaus it is successful in describing the experimental values ( crossection and angular distirbutions in this case) also in cases where the classical theory fails ( I do not know if or at what level the classical bremsstrahlung model may be failing).