# Accelerated charges and photons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, virtual-particles

It is well known that any accelerated or decelerated charge (electron, proton, etc) must emit photons, or bremsstrahlung.  Is this because the photon is the medium of exchange of the momentum of charged particles, and thus in the process of "slowing down" the charged particle emits a "jet" of photons almost like thrusters on a spacecraft?  I wanted to see if the analogy is correct. But if so, I thought bremsstrahlung tended to be in all directions rather than directional with the direction of the acceleration?

Comment: please  see this answer of mine for the quantum diagrams for  bremsstrahlung https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187934/quantum-mechanics-prediction-for-bremsstrahlung/187935#187935 . Classical electromagnetic waves emerge from the confluence of a huge number of such interactions.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This analogy is not correct in the sense that the photons emitted are not the reason why the particle changes velocity. They appear as a consequence of momentum transfer, not as a cause (like a thruster would be). The reason bremsstrahlung happens is that electromagnetic interactions propagate at the speed of light, so changing the source field abruptly creates ripples in the EM field that must propagate to infinity. The quantum particle-like description of the phenomena is that a hard momentum transfer to a charged particle makes the soft photon emissions that dress an external line go on-shell (become real photons).

Comment: So if I'm understanding, the classical electric field lines are, from a quantum perspective, streams of virtual photons?

Comment: No. I'm sorry if my comment confused you, quantum field theories do not translate into classical theories so straightforwardly. In particular, there is no direct analog of electric or magnetic field lines because the dynamical variables are the gauge field $A_{\mu}$ and its curvature $F_{\mu \nu}$, not the would-be classical fields.

Comment: Ah, just a shot in the dark on my part. That is good information.